# clientX and clientY not giving correct mouse pointer location

Tags: javascript

I wrote this simple code to print a small dot on the location where I clicked with the mouse pointer:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pane').click(function(e){
        var pixel = $('<div />')
                  .addClass('pixel')
                  .css({
                      top: e.clientY,
                      left: e.clientX
                  });

        $('#pane').append(pixel)
    });
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DsPLG/1/) I created. When I click anywhere inside the rectangle, a small dot is printed in that location. But the problem is that dot is not printed where the mouse pointer's `tip` was. See the below image to see what I meant:-

[image: screenshot showing dot printed in a different location]

I tried in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I don't see that bug in Chrome 19 / Ubuntu

Comment: What is your screen resolution ?

Comment: I tried in Ubuntu and Windows XP. Both in Firefox and Chrome. My screen is 1024x768 :( and I tried in a wide screen also. Everywhere I checked, the problem is visible. The variation is only by a few pixels.

Comment: I don't know whether it is useful or not but you can read it http://help.dottoro.com/ljsqnefp.php

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly,

Zoom your page and check,

i have changed pixel height and width for better understanding from 2px to 3px.
and drawing from e.clientX -1 and e.clientY -1 position so it looks exactly center.

You can find [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DsPLG/2/)

Comment: It looks closer now. But still looks more off when page is zoomed out to normal view.

Comment: All these examples don't work if you resize the page in order that the scroller appears...

Answer (score 0):

The most examples I've found don't work if there are a scrolled page... I used this algorythm in order to get the position:

```
var getOffsets = function($event){
    var p = {};
    var body = "search the document for the body element";
    p.x = body.offsetLeft;
    p.y = body.offsetTop;
    while (body.offsetParent) {
        p.x = p.x + body.offsetParent.offsetLeft;
        p.y = p.y + body.offsetParent.offsetTop;
        if (body == document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            body = body.offsetParent;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

However, after that you have to consider also other elements, im my case:

```
var GetExactClickPosition = function($event){

    var tr = $($event.target);
    if ($event.target.localName != 'tr'){
        tr = $($event.target).closest('tr');
    }

    var listDiv = $($event.target).closest('div');
    var p = getOffsets($event);
    var container = $('#mailingListExcludeMenuContainer');

    container.css({
        top: p.y - listDiv.scrollTop() - tr.height() - container.height() + $event.offsetY + "px",
        left: p.x + $event.offsetX + "px"
    });
    container.show();
};
```

I have a list with scroller inside the main scroller of the page...
I used it in order to show a little menu at the position of the mouse click.